# How to make the ruby version match the gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

My Ruby on Rails server is failing to execute because of an error that says my ruby version is 2.3.3 but my gemfile is 2.3.1. How do I fix it ?

Comment: Please add what did you try

Comment: Gem install bundler and I can't install rvm

Comment: Please add in question as well

Comment: The question is the server is not working because of that error. Should downgrade ruby or upgrade the gem file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try selecting 2.3.1 ruby version from RVM by this command

```
rvm use 2.3.1
```

or change the ruby version to 2.3.3 in the gem file